# get a xml response according to the parameters passed in python

Tags: python, xml

I would like to  get a response, by post method, and outputting the response on my webpage. So far, when I'm injecting directly in the url, I'm getting the right response, but in my code, I'm getting the `error 15` , according to the api.

Here is my url which needs to return a xml response .

`https://xml2sms.gsm.co.za/send/?username=y&password=y&number1=27825551234&message1=This+is+a+test&number2=27825551234&message2=This+is+a+test+2'`

Here is my code. It does post but returns an error 15. According to the api, I'm building the error 15 is, means destination out of range.

This is my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
xml = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<a></a>"""
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'} # 
print requests.request("POST",'https://xml2sms.gsm.co.za/send/?
username=y&password=y&
number1=27825551234&message1=This+is+a+test&
number2=2
7825551234&message2=This+is+a+test+2', data=xml, headers=headers).text
```

Comment: Problem is not in the code, but in API usage. Please check params you're passing to that endpoint. By the way, instead of `requests.request("POST", ...)` you may use `requests.post(...)`

Comment: Hi @bakatrouble , though i'm using  requests.post,  i'm still having the same output in my terminal  with the error 150 .  <aatsms><submitresult number="" result="0" key="0" Action="not queued - Error 150" error="150" /></aatsms>

Comment: I think you should rather contact support of service you're trying to use

Comment: Alright , will do. But first ., i would try to get  it right. Thanks

Comment: @bakatrouble , i got it right, shoot , just use the requests.get instead of using the request.post .. Actually they do not accept post.  Thank you.

Comment: typo correction.